# RDP App over wifi react (crash) differently then when wired

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop

On a TS 2012 R2 I have an app that is only accessing local resources.
When I connect in RDP from the local network or even from the Internet from a wired connection everything is fine.

But when I RDP from Wifi, the application crashes.
Not my session, not TS, not my computer, not my connection... the APP crashes on the TS (this application has caused ... bla bla bla)

Like if that application that is running from a shared drive on the local network knows that I am wifi (how can it know) and due to insuffiennt speed it crashes.

As I said, the RDP connection is stable. I can browse the Internet normally and the speed id fine. I can start MS-Word and type characters with no latency.

Everything is fine except for that application.
Local drives are not accessible just in case the app would try to come back on my local C: drive. Wifi somewhow affect this app. Can RDP caching on a slower RDP connection cause the kind of behavior ?
RD

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2010/01/14/remote-desktop-gateway-client-fails-authentication-with-your-user-account-is-not-authorized-to-access-the-rd-gateway.aspx maybe help